# Django template tag inside HTML input tag (value attribute)

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Is there any way for template tags of the `{% %}` sort to work in the `<input type="submit">` HTML tag?

For instance, imagine the variable `text` contains `You're cool :-)`, and I have a custom template tag that turns `:-)` into the corresponding custom emoji I've designed.

Then, the following wouldn't work, would it: `<input type="submit" name="text" value="{% emoticons %}{{ text }}{% endemoticons %}">`

I understand I can also use `<button type="submit" name="text">{% emoticons %}{{ text }}{% endemoticons %}</button>`, but a button fundamentally doesn't overflow elegantly to the next line like regular text does, hence I'm trying to avoid it.

Anyone got a neat workaround to this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description of the example problem it looks like you should be implementing a template filter, not a template tag. In any case both filters and tags will work. But the usage will look like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="text" value="{% emoticons text %}">
```

In case of a filter:

```
<input type="submit" name="text" value="{{text|emoticons}}">
```

Comment: Gotcha. I was also wondering whether there'd be any performance difference when taking the template filter approach. Any musings?

Comment: From performance perspective I am not sure if there is any difference at all given the same implementation of your code. Both would end up being a function call. In the sense of how Django parses/compiles a template I don't know if there's any difference, but you shouldn't be concerned with that unless you have huge templates, or generate huge output. In which case Jinja2 may be more appropriate for performance. Make sure to read the docs on custom tags/filters and avoiding XSS.